# Como fazer para que o gif comece parado e quando eu passe o mouse por cima ele rode o gif

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Salve galera, estou fazendo um projeto para a faculdade usando HTML, CSS e Javascript, porém, eu fiz alguns painéis e coloquei alguns gifs, preciso que os gifs comecem inativados, ou seja, estáticos, como se você abrisse no google, e quando passe o mouse por cima ele rode o gif, porém, quero que quando ele tire o mouse novamente ele pare o gif e volte ao estado inicial, sem ele rodar o gif.

````
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Projeto Charlie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">
    </head>
<body>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Luffy.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Luffy.gif" alt="Luffy" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Luffy">Monkey D. Luffy</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Zoro.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Zoro.gif" alt="Zoro" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Zoro">Roronoa Zoro</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Nami.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Nami.gif" alt="Nami" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Nami">Nami</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Usopp.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Usopp.gif" alt="Usopp" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Usopp">God Usopp</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Sanji.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Sanji.gif" alt="Sanji" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Sanji">Vinsmoke Sanji</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Chopper.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Chopper.gif" alt="Chopper" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Chopper">Chopper</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Robin.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Robin.gif" alt="Robin" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Robin">Nico Robin</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Franky.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Franky.gif" alt="Franky" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Franky">Franky</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Brook.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Brook.gif" alt="Brook" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Brook">Brook</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Gif_Jimbe.gif">
      <img src="galeria/Gif_Jimbe.gif" alt="Jimbe" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Jimbe">Jimbe</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Eren Yeager.png">
      <img src="galeria/Eren Yeager.png" alt="Eren" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Eren">Eren Yaeger</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Sukuna.png">
      <img src="galeria/Sukuna.png" alt="Sukuna" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Sukuna">Sukuna</div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="galeria/Zenitsu.jpg">
      <img src="galeria/Zenitsu.jpg" alt="Zenitsu" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="Zenitsu">Zenitsu</div>
  </div>
</body>
    </html>```

Meu CSS está externo!

```div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  }
  
  div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
  div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  div.Zenitsu {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Luffy {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Zoro {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Nami {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Usopp {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Sanji {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Chopper {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Robin {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Franky {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Brook {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Jimbe {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Eren {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  div.Sukuna {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }```
````

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples que eu encontrei de fazer isso seria assim:

- Primeiro você deveria fazer uma cópia de todos os gifs.
- Cada cópia deveria ser salva no formato jpg.
- Ou seja cada foto teria um arquivo .gif e outro .jpg
- Depois você teria que mudar no html todas as fotos para o formato .jpg
- Criar um função no JS que acontece no momento de passar o mouse.
- Nessa função você mude o src da foto para .gifs

Criei um exemplo que ilustra bem isso:

HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" id="foto" alt="">
```

CSS

```
#foto {
  width: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
let foto = document.getElementById("foto")

foto.addEventListener("mouseenter", mudarFoto)

function mudarFoto() {
  foto.setAttribute("src", "https://gizmodo.uol.com.br/wp-content/blogs.dir/8/files/2021/02/nyan-cat-1.gif")
}
```

Lembrando que essa é apenas uma maneira de fazer isso.

Answer (score -2):

A maneira mais simples é inserir uma imagem no formato jpeg que represente o estado pausado do gif sobrepondo o gif real e alterar a opacidade da prévia para 0 quando o usuário passar o mouse sobre a imagem usando a pseudo-classe `hover`.

```css
.previa {
  position:absolute;
  background: white;
}

.previa:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="previa" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-gZiu96oTuu4/Uag5oWLQHfI/AAAAAAAABSE/pl1W8n91hH0/w140-h165-no/Homer-Static.png">
  <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/i1RprwcvxhbN2TAMunNxS4RiNVT0DvlD9FNQCvPFuJ0=w140-h165-no">
</div>
```

Essa forma de obter o primeiro frame do gif talvez possa ajudar: [imagecreatefromgif](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).